# Allow to Identity server 3 to Authenticate user from FormsAuthentication cookie

Tags: identityserver3, form-authentication

I have some applications and a identity server which are working perfectly fine.
Couple of my old applications are still using Form based authentication and for the purpose of achieving SSO I am using machine key and domain combinations in my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="SSO" 
         loginUrl="http://site1.example.com/login.aspx" 
         defaultUrl="http://example.com" 
         domain="example.com" slidingExpiration="true">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="35D679385CE8" decryptionKey="55D456A"  
  validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
```

It helps me achieve SSO.

Now the problem is after getting authenticated from webforms application if user navigates to any of my new application they got redirected to identity for login.
what i want is there any way that identity server authenticate user if FormsAuthentication cookie is available. 
Its not possible for now to change my old applications.

Answer (score 2):

First, see my previous question/answer to leverage FormsAuth Tickets in Owin: [OWIN Self-Host CookieAuthentication & Legacy .NET 4.0 Application / FormsAuthenticationTicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251550/owin-self-host-cookieauthentication-legacy-net-4-0-application-formsauthent/23773674#23773674)

Once you have the ability to decrypt/encrypt your FormsAuth cookie, you can leverage that in IdentityServer.

Since your hosting is most likely different than mine, use this as a reference:

`/` -> our main api appBuilder
`/auth` -> our identityServer

Our main API appBuilder uses the cookie auth middleware as described in the associated SO post (link) above.

IdenityServer app composition root:

```
appBuilder.Map("/auth", idsrvApp =>
{
     idsrvApp.Use((context, task) =>
     {
         // since we can authenticate using "Cookies" auth,
         // we must add the principal to the env so we can reuse it in the UserService
         // oddly, the Context.Authentication.User will clear by the time it gets there and we can't rely on it
         // my best guess is because IdentityServer is not authenticated (no cookie set)
         if (context.Authentication.User != null && context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
             context.Environment.Add("auth.principal", context.Authentication.User);

         return task.Invoke();
     });

     idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(isOptions);
});
```

UserService.cs

```
    public async Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // if we already have an authenticated user/principal then bypass local authentication
        if (_Context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||
            _Context.Environment.ContainsKey("auth.principal"))
        {
            var principal = _Context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                ? _Context.Authentication.User
                : (ClaimsPrincipal)_Context.Environment["auth.principal"];

            context.AuthenticateResult =
                new AuthenticateResult(); // set AuthenticateResult

            return;
        }
    }
```

**Please Note:**

1. Use this as an example.
2. Enabling cookie auth on your app or api *MAY* unsuspectingly compromise your security to CSRF attacks. Ensure you're aware of this attack vector and take the necessary steps to reduce this risk.